# Finding the domain $y=\log_{2x}(7)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

> > The question is to find the domain of $y=\log_{2x}(7)$

What I have attempted:

$$y=\log_{2x}(7)$$

$$ y = \frac{\log(7)}{\log(2x)}$$

$$ y = \frac{\log(7)}{\log(2)+\log(x)}$$

The denominator has to be greater than $0$ so

$${\log(2)+\log(x)} > 0$$

$$ \log(x) > -\log(2) $$

$$ \log(x) > \log(2^{-1}) $$

$$\log(x) > \log(\frac{1}{2}) $$

$$ x > \frac{1}{2} $$

So the domain should be $x \in R $ and $ x> \frac{1}{2} $ on wolfram alpha it says there is also another thing I should consider which is $ 0 < x <  \frac{1}{2} $ how did they get that?

Comment: The denominator can't BE zero; it can be negative, though.

Comment: @CarlHeckman considering it is precalculus it most likely cannot be negative either as that results in complex numbers.

Comment: @ZelosMalum $2x$ can't be negative (or zero); the base of a log must be $>0$ and not equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this way too complicated. Just remember that $\log_a(7)$ makes sense for any $a>0$ other than $a=1$. (You can write $7 = a^x$ for some $x$ any time $a>0$, except when $a=1$, since any power of $1$ is still $1$.)

Comment: But not $a=1$ ....

Comment: Oops. :) Typed too quickly. Thanks.